# Lifting a function to ~> in scalaz

Tags: scala, monads, functor, scalaz, kind-projector

I have the following types and declarations:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

trait Container[T] 
type FreeContainer[A] = Free[Container, A]
type FreeFreeContainer[A] = Free[FreeContainer, A]

val fc: FreeContainer[Int]
val ffc: FreeFreeContainer[Int]

val t: Container ~> Id

val tranformed: Int = fc.foldMap(t)   //ok
val tranformed2: Int = ffc.foldMap(t) //error
```

Is it possible to lift `Container ~> Id` to `FreeContainer ~> Id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, via `foldMap`:

```
val t: Container ~> Id

val tt: FreeContainer ~> Id = new (FreeContainer ~> Id) {
  def apply[A](fc: FreeContainer[A]): A = fc.foldMap(t)
}
```

Using the [polymorphic lambda syntax of kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector#polymorphic-lambda-values), this can be simplified to

```
val tt: FreeContainer ~> Id = λ[FreeContainer ~> Id](_.foldMap(t))
```

So you can do

```
val tranformed2: Int = ffc.foldMap(λ[FreeContainer ~> Id](_.foldMap(t)))
```

Alternatively, you can just do two consecutive `foldMap`s, the first one with the identity natural transformation:

```
val tranformed2: Int = ffc.foldMap(NaturalTransformation.refl[FreeContainer]).foldMap(t)
```

Comment: I have the question about the last approach. I don't quite understand the sense of `ffc.foldMap(NaturalTransformation.refl[FreeContainer])`. Sort of unlifting?

Comment: `NaturalTransformation.refl[FreeContainer]` is a natural transformation `FreeContainer ~> FreeContainer` that does not actually do anything. Note that `foldMap` requires a natural transformation where the target type is a monad. But `FreeContainer` is already a monad, so there's no need to transform it into something else; we can just fold directly into it, so we use a no-op transformation.

Comment: The analogy with `List` (the free monoid) is that `foldMap` using the identity function is just `fold` (and the element type is already a monoid). Unfortunately, in scalaz there's currently no analogy of `fold` on the `Free` monad, but that method could be added. (The method on `Free` called [`fold`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/2fdd887f536e17d59b586b93bf8639e5b84eccd9/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Free.scala#L112-L114) does something else.)